# Display turns off when watching videos (then video starts to lag), how to fix it?

Tags: video, display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I stop the screensaver from turning on when I watching online videos?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144621/how-do-i-stop-the-screensaver-from-turning-on-when-i-watching-online-videos)

Okay, here's the thing - - On my Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit installation, I have the display set to turn off automatically after 3 minutes of inactivity.

There are two problems now:

- the display turns off even when I am watching videos. But I don't want to keep fiddling my mouse or keyboard when I am watching a movie.
- Okay, like I said above, the display turns off, then I move the mouse a bit each time, and the display turns back on. But now, the video doesn't play properly, it lags. A lot actually.

Are these issues common? Can these be fixed?